# In microservice, how do you make sure that all services get updated when more than one micro service is affected?

Tags: c#, docker, architecture, microservices, software-design

Example

Online checkout:

User adds item to shopping cart, clicks checkout and pays for order via credit card.

1. Order is created via OrderMicroservice
2. a) Order is updated with “Complete” status via OrderMicroservice

   b) Payment is processed via credit card and logged via PaymentMicroservice

   c) Invoice is created and emailed to user via InvoiceMicroservice

For some reason the invoice microservice failed, the database storage is full or email failed to send, OR payment failed but the order has already been marked as “complete”, do we need to roll back the database? or what do we do here to make sure that the entire workflow has been executed correctly?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need to change status flow for your orders. See, not only Invoice microservice may fail - any step may (payment could be rejected as an example). Instead of next flow:

```
create order --> mark as completed --> do payment --> create invoice
```

consider something like this

```
create order -->  mark as "waiting for payment" --> do payment -->
--> mark as "ready for invoice" --> create invoice --> mark as completed
```

As the result, you will have orders with different statuses and will be able to process them differently in the case of fail.

---

In additional, you need to think whether each step could be retried later if failed. As a rough example, you may have some scheduled job, that generates invoice mail for all orders with status "ready for invoice". So if the job is failed for order, it will re-try to generate mail again at the next round.

Comment: This looks like something for an ESB and Saga to make happen.  Ideally and OrderItem command kicks off an Ordering Saga that then waits for events from the other services to then update Order Status once all of the other dependent services complete.